# Meteor Deps Recompute Fails

Tags: meteor

Clicking the previous button will retrieves the previous date's collections. For example, if the current date is 2013-04-05, then the previous button will retrieve all collections for 2013-04-04, and so on. However, the automatic update does not works. The new collection of events never did appears and an exception occurs.

Additionally, I have also run into this error if I tries to create a new event. Only by refreshing the page do I see the new event in the collection.

### Error

```
Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Error copying attribute ',': Error:     InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5
at Function.Spark._Patcher._copyAttributes (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/patch.js?   e76412b922e47b6c2c1f890e3bc10fd13bdecfef:494:19)
at Spark._Patcher.match (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/patch.js?e76412b922e47b6c2c1f890e3bc10fd13bdecfef:249:26)
at http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/patch.js?e76412b922e47b6c2c1f890e3bc10fd13bdecfef:61:23
at visitNodes (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/patch.js?e76412b922e47b6c2c1f890e3bc10fd13bdecfef:17:11)
at Object.Spark._patch (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/patch.js?e76412b922e47b6c2c1f890e3bc10fd13bdecfef:31:3)
at http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?4af332696fb84f1c71f2e678ad0a267755b2b828:638:13
at LiveRange.operate (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/liverange/liverange.js?5e6bc5ba11645802c3440658c75fcc2277537dd1:458:9)
at http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?4af332696fb84f1c71f2e678ad0a267755b2b828:633:11
at withEventGuard (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?4af332696fb84f1c71f2e678ad0a267755b2b828:103:16)
at Object.Spark.renderToRange (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?4af332696fb84f1c71f2e678ad0a267755b2b828:632:3) logging.js:40

Exception from Deps afterFlush function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'previousSibling' of null
at findPosition (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/liverange/liverange.js?5e6bc5ba11645802c3440658c75fcc2277537dd1:177:12)
at new LiveRange (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/liverange/liverange.js?5e6bc5ba11645802c3440658c75fcc2277537dd1:126:18)
at notifyWatchers (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?4af332696fb84f1c71f2e678ad0a267755b2b828:86:19)
at http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?4af332696fb84f1c71f2e678ad0a267755b2b828:404:5
at _.extend.flush (http://0.0.0.0:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?651e87591167f4286e96438ff2566ba3357bff99:231:11)
```

### Code for finding a list of events, the code under the else is the relevant part

```
Template.event_manager.list = () ->
   if (Session.get("events_toggl"))
     Events.find({user_id: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {seconds: 1}})
   else
     d = Session.get("eventnav")
     start = moment().subtract("days",d).startOf("day")._d
     end = moment().subtract("days", d).endOf("end")._d
     Events.find({user_id: Meteor.userId(), date: {$gte: start, $lt: end} })
```

### clicking previous will trigger an update in the list function above

```
'click #previous' : () ->
    d = Session.get("eventnav")
    d += 1
    Session.set("eventnav", d)
```

### part where we decide to render a list of events

```
  {{#each list}}
    {{> event}}
  {{/each}}
```

### template for individual events

```
<template name="event">
  <tr class={{status}}>
    <td>{{seconds}}</td>
    <td><p id="date-{{_id}}" class="date">{{date}}</p></td>
    <td><p id="name-{{_id}}" class="name">{{name}}</p></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="select" value="select" /><br /><br /><input type="button" id="destroy" value="delete" /></td>
  </tr>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and it was just multiple ids with the same value.

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/TypeError_-_Cannot_read_property_nodeName_of_null

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. It turns out the error is related to invalid HTML buttons.

```
<input type="button", id="previous", value="previous" />
<input type="button", id="next", value="forward" />
```

---

The simple fix is to eliminate all commas.

Answer (score 0):

I had no duplicate ids but removing the `id` attribute of the list elements solved the issue:

faulty HTML:

```
  {{#each formDatas}}
  <tr class="formDataRow" id="{{_id}}">
     {{#each ../this}}
     <td>{{getData ../this this }}</td>
     {{/each}}
     <td><input id="{{_id}}" class="row-selector" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

HTML which does not cause the error

```
  {{#each formDatas}}
  <tr class="formDataRow" id="{{_id}}">
     {{#each ../this}}
     <td>{{getData ../this this }}</td>
     {{/each}}
     <td><input class="row-selector" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

notice the missing `id` attribute from the `input`

you usually do not need the `id` attribute as the `this` object in the event refers to the data element of the loop